# Storing hindi in lang.properties in java and retrieving it

Tags: java, encoding

I want to read hindi text from lang.properties(JAVA.util.properties) file.
I am using eclipse IDE.

First of all how can I save(or write) hindi letter in .properties file

Secondly how to read the string from my java class.

**lang.properties**

```
hindiText=साहिलसाहिल
```

**Java Class**

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(MyCalss.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("lang.properties"));
String hindi=prop.getProperty("hindiText");
```

It's not working.

Comment: Where is your lang.properties stored?

Comment: Read Java Internationization tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/

Comment: In future, please understand that "its not working" is *not* an adequate description of your problem. It's the software equivalent of asking a doctor to diagnose your illness on the basis of "I don't feel well". Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 4):

[As documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29), `Properties.load(InputStream)` will always use the ISO-8859-1 encoding, and that encoding doesn't handle the characters you're interested in.

Options:

- Wrap your stream in an `InputStreamReader` and specify the encoding explicitly
- Use Unicode escaping (e.g `\u1234`) in the file for any characters not in ISO-8859-1 (and make sure the file is saved as ISO-8859-1)